# SVM (Support Vector Machine) opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I'm new to machine learning. I'm doing a project by using opencv open source library. My issue is that I don't have experience in Machine Learning. I have extracted features from different images and I have evaluated them, now I want to classify objects in those images by using SVM but I don't know what to do. BTW, I used 3 different feature extractors, SIFT, SURF and FAST feature detector (with their descriptors)

Can you give me the guide and some examples to classify more than 5 objects in the background, such as coffee cups, coca cola, basket balls etc...

I'm doing my project in C++, environment (UBUNTU).

Comment: At what point are you stuck? Could you narrow your question down to specific problem areas?

Comment: I am in the beginning, I have done only the feature extraction. So my point is what is next? I want to classify several objects, what I have done so far is only the feature extraction

Comment: What lead to your choice of SVM's as a classifier? If you look at your features, could you use them to classify the objects by hand?

Comment: I don't get your point here, but I want to use svm classifier as a task in my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the information provided, all I can give you is the following list:

- [category-level classification tutorial](http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/events/cvml2011/materials/practical-classification/) from the CVML2011 summer school. It includes code (for you unfortunately in Matlab) which can help you to understand the concept behind it.
- paper called ["A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification"](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) which clearly explains how to prepare the data, train and test SVM
- and of course the OpenCV documentation on [svm training](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train-auto)

As already pointed out by @jillesdewit you should try to be more specific.